# Django-React App Static/Media Serving Method

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles, django-react

Me and my friend have started a project including Django, Django REST and React.

I have a little experience in deploying standalone django apps but not in django-react.

The plan for now is, that the admin will upload pictures via django-admin and the website will be displaying new pictures as admin is going to upload them. (If thats even possible with this combination.)

And the question is: How am I supposed to serve static files? I know that one of the best solutions is to store static files (photos, templates, css etc.) on things like Amazon AWS S3 if working on standalone django project, but I have no idea if thats the right solution in our case because as I said, I've never done anything like that and I can't find any answers for my question and every setup tutorial doesn't say anything about that.

And if that's the best solution, could anyone please give me some link for that tutorial or anything that could help us? Im responsible for Django and my friend for React.

Thank you.

[edit] The website will be hosted on heroku

Comment: The Django+React tutorial https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/ How many picture are you planning to have? You can serve picture from `media` dir with nginx. Should be the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can use AWS S3 to serve static files like images for your project. Here is an article that explains configuring Django to AWS S3

https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/